# jquery hide rows of divs between two divs when having certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="CntWrapper_CntMain_ssm_ctl00_ctl01" class="matrix">
  <div class="CollapseGroup1"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell_24">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell_24">
      <span class="label-passive">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CollapseGroupClose1"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to manipulate above HTML code sample. It's a simplified version the actual HTML code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CollapseGroup1').nextUntil('.CollapseGroupClose1',').css( "display", "none" );
  });
</script>
```

This script hides all the div with class 'row' between the two divs called collapsegroup and collapsegroupclose.

However, I only want to hide the div elements with class 'Row' when any of these rows contain at least one span with class 'label-passive'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CollapseGroup1').nextUntil('.CollapseGroupClose1','div[.label-passive]').css( "display", "none" );
  });
</script>
```

Just simply hiding any row div when there is a span with label-passive is not good enough. There can be rows with 'label-passive' span classes outside these collapsegroup divs that I don't want to hide.

I want to hide **all** rows between two collapsegroup tags, even when just one of these rows actually has a child span element with class 'label-passive'.

Comment: your question is too long, nobody will bother reading it all..... consider cutting it by half and supply a demo page

Comment: especially cut out whatever is already working. We should be able to quickly understand what your issue is right from the start

Comment: I've rewritten the thing. The use case does need some explaining, so there's still some text, but I've probably shortened the question by half. I hope this makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading your question once.. Twice.. Trice.. I think you want this:
(pro-tip: try to keep your questions as simple as possible, using pseudo-code if you must)

```
$('.label-passive').parents('._row').hide();
```

If this isn't completely what you wanted, leave a comment and I'll try to improve the answer.

**Edit: Improved answer as OP improved his question:**

Maybe this will help you further then:

```
$('.CollapseGroup1').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".label-passive").length != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Sadly not, I rewrote my post again, with just really simple sample HTML code. It's admittedly a lot more readable now.

I want to hide any and all rows (divs) between two divs with class 'Collapsegroup' and 'Collapsegroupclose', based on whether just even one of those rows has a span with class 'label-passive.'

Comment: @MaartendeVries No problem, I checked your edit, and improved my answer. Please let me know if this is better.

Comment: You're edited answer doesn't work either. Here you're assuming that the div tags that I want to edit are within the collapsegroup node. This is not the case. I need all divs between the two divs with either collapsegroup and collapsegroupclose. In the HTML example, that means that I want both divs with class 'row' to be hidden, just because one of these two divs has a span within with class 'label-passive'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```
$('div.row:has(.label-passive)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `closest()`:

```
$('span.label-passive').closest('div.row').hide();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('span.label-passive').closest('div.row').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CntWrapper_CntMain_ssm_ctl00_ctl01" class="matrix">
  <div class="CollapseGroup1"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell_24">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell_24">
      <span class="label-passive">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CollapseGroupClose1"></div>
</div>
```